# Trigger iOS Siri shortcut from a Mac

Tags: macos, ios, shortcut, siri, shortcuts-app

I tried to ask Siri to run my shortcut from my MacBook pro but it did not work... Does anyone know if it is possible to run a IOS shortcut from a Mac?

Comment: what was the problem "did not work" ?

Comment: My shortcut on IOS is triggered with a voice command. The same command did not work with Siri on Mac, Siri did not recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Apple's webpage on [How to use Siri on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206993) has no indication that using Siri on your Mac can control your iPhone.